# Receiving a string in a different charset and displaying on screen

Tags: javascript, iframe, serialization, encoding, character-encoding

I'm trying to display a full html page, received as string via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    // ... params
    success: function (html) {            
        var doc = document.getElementById('iframe-id').contentWindow.document;
        doc.open();
        doc.write(html);
        doc.close();
    }
});
```

The problem is that for utf-8-only strings it works properly but when an html has a different charset, the iframe does not show the characters properly.

I've checked the response on the chrome response visualizer and it shows the string correctly.

How can I show this content correctly?

PS.: I'm not married to the idea of using an iframe.

EDIT 1:
The page already comes with content-type:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-2022-jp">`

But does not come with:

`<meta charset="...">`

Comment: Have you try to rewrite the `html` string to change this tag `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to have the right charset ?

Comment: @Kornflexx I've edited the question to clarify that concern.

Comment: I am not sure it would work, but you can try to use this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8 to encode your `html` variable to utf8.